# Give CSS-property highest priority

Tags: html, css

I want to give highest priority to the `<h1>`. In my example I want the background for the `<h1>`-element to show instead of what is specified for the `<a>`-element.

```
h1{
  background-color:blue1!important
}
```

But it does not work in the context below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
a{
  background-color:red
}
h1{
  background-color:blue
}
</style>
<body>

<h1><a>My First Heading</a></h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: h1{background-color:blue !important;}  
try this.

Comment: highest priority means @IshanJain the class which is override to all other class css effect in it.

Comment: @jigneshkheni it's not working in this case ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
h1 a,h1{
    background-color:blue
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/24cgn/)

Comment: Thank. wow!  it's is what answer i actually want..thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good practice to use `!important` because you breaks natural cascading in your stylesheet. Whenever you have the chance not to use it, do not use it.

The most specific selector always *wins* so I suggest to use an `id` for your `a` element.
Have a look on [this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) article in order to understand *specifity rules* of css.

Example :

```
a#special-link{
    background-color:red
}

<h1><a id="special-link">My First Heading</a></h1>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe adding an id solution does not fit, but this was just an example. In your case adding a class would be enough too. Or using a selector, as the accepted answer. Howewer, if you want to use the same style for your h1 > a over your html page, then you'll end up creating lots of selectors (I assume you'll not have always <h1><a>.. structure ).

Comment: yeah yes you right in case of where we going to actual use. tnks

Answer (score 1):

Try like this ,

```
h1 a{
    background-color:blue !important;
    }
```

Comment: h1 a{
    background-color:blue 
    } 
a{
    background-color:red!important
    
} it's not working

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, priority means overriding the property. for that we can use

1. attribute '!important'
2. Referring through the parent class ,div etc.

In this scenario I think you want blue color all over.

```
h1 a {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I have read all the answers but I shall suggest to use child>combinator to get the proper result using css style rules.There may be a lot of <a> tag may be in <p> </p> tag .So your priority is to set only H1 tag so use the following rules.Don't break the css rules.

a{
  background-color:red;
}
h1>a,h1{
  background-color:blue;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the  (anchor tag if you aren't going to utilize it) if none of these worked try to change to

```
    <h1 style="background-color:blue;"> My First Heading </h1>
```

or changing the line to this

```
    <h1><a style="background-color:blue;">My First Heading</a></h1>
```

Comment: hey i said above (hiral) is answer suite to my program. you are totally changing my question. and giving me answer..it's not correct answer to my question . anyways jake thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see this

Answer (score 0):

you should write `!important` after property,like so:

```
    .example{
    background-color:blue !important;
}
```

[readmore](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)

Comment: no..it's not a answer of my question...actually i used it before but it's not working in highest priority